# Autocomplete is not working as expected

Tags: jquery

I am getting `autocomplete is not a function`  while executing my jsp page.

Perhaps it is something simple I have overlooked

```
'$('selector').autocomplete({source:myarray});'
```

Script tags

```
'<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="js/plugins/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom/general.js"></script>'
```

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/7RkDq/ Are you sure you're loading the libraries before initializing the autocomplete?

Comment: your code above doesnt make enough sense to answer your question.  The scripts you link to and your autocomplete call are in quotes for start.  Can you please give us the exact code?

Comment: make sure your script is added after the required libraries are included and it is executed in dom ready

Comment: The quotes are used to point what is code and what isn't the OP did not use any code tags. He also did it with the error he got, I think that's not the problem.

Comment: Yeah, I missed the quotes (which likely should have been backticks) when I edited, now we are sort of deadlocked.

Comment: Maybe 'selector' does not have this function?! Did you try to use an existing selector like "p" or "#anyID"?

Comment: Please post the entire error.  That error wouldn't come from this code.  If autocomplete wasn't loaded, the error would be `TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'autocomplete'`

Comment: This is the error iam getting thats it $('#myid').autocomplete is not a function

Comment: @devdot Selectors don't have functions, the jQuery object (`$`) does. It's not possible to get a "has no method" error for only some selectors.

Comment: @Juhana of course a selector string does not have these functions, I did mean the jQuery object created by the selector. If jQuery objects always have all possible methods - whether the selector actually selects something or not - never mind my previous comment.

Comment: @devdot A jQuery object always has all possible methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your document has this general format and order.  The error is likely caused by the autocomplete plugin not being loaded.

```
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>
<div>
body stuff
</div>
<script src="..../jquery.js"></script>
<script src="..../jqueryui.js"></script>
<script>
var myArray = ['foo', 'bar'];
$('selector').autocomplete({source:myarray});
</script>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: Make sure there is an object "selector". For instance and DOM object with the ID "auto" would have the selector "#auto". And the DOM has to be loaded when you try to execute on the given DOM object.